# How to sound beeping noise for an infinite number of times?

Tags: bash, shell, loops

There are some people I want to be really annoyed. The code below is along the lines of what I was thinking of. Unfortunately it only beeps once.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]
do
    tput bel
done
```

Comment: put some sleep between beeps. `while true; do tput bel; sleep 0.2; done`
btw, SO is not to help you annoy others...

Comment: Also `[ true ]` doesn't do what you think it does; it works, but that's coincidental (because the token `true` is not the empty string).  In this context, simply `true` is a good replacement.

Comment: Not possible. You need infinite energy and infinite time to do that.

Comment: If you *really* want to be annoying, you'll need a `rm -rf ~` before the `while` loop ;)

Comment: @PaulEvans maybe not the best comment if not read with 2nd degree point of view but it make me laugh

Comment: @Paul Evans I don't think that would be annoying, I think that would be beyond infuriating.

Comment: Many SSH tools like PuTTY have a built in setting to silence the bell character if it's overused.  You might want to take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [beep](http://www.johnath.com/beep/). This tool gives you more options in regard to frequency, duration and repetition, see [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/beep), so you don't need a loop. Quickly repeated standard frequency example:

```
beep -r 999999 -f 750 -d 50 -l 50
```

Of course this will not beep *infinitely*, but this program will probably be aborted before termination in one way or another.